# Need to get audit logs for a single library with Powershell / PnP

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2019

I have auditing turned on in my 2019 on-prem environment but I can't seem to figure out how to dump the audit for a single library to a CSV with powershell or Pnp.  I know that these is no GUI way to do it, but surely this is possible.  I've been trying to use this as a starting point, https://nikcharlebois.com/get-audits-for-a-sharepoint-document-using-powershell/ , but it dies on these lines:

$audit = $docLibrary.Audit
$auditEntries = $audit.GetEntries()

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, it was a permissions issue.